# Is this the location of the GAC?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, gac

Is this the location of the GAC?

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
```

If so, then what is `C:\Windows\assembly`?

Comment: See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gauravseth/archive/2006/03/07/545104.aspx). Search that page for text "GAC in 64-bit platforms". Also look at [this](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.383883.5)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19980650/945456

Answer (score 10):

The answer depends on the version of the .NET Framework being used. Multiple versions can be installed side by side (which is probably the case for you), and programs written for an older version use that version if it's installed.

**Before 4.0**
All versions before 4.0 use `%WINDIR%\assembly` (in your case, `C:\Windows\assembly`) for the GAC. This directory uses a special Explorer view (the Assembly Cache Viewer) to view and manage the GAC.

**Since 4.0**
Versions since 4.0 use `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly` (in your case, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly`) for the GAC. Since 4.0, the Assembly Cache Viewer is obsolete. Explorer displays the GAC directory just like a regular directory.